# SSH after port change

Tags: ssh, firewall, port

I changed the SSH port on my server, but I then forgot to open a hole in the firewall for that port specifically.
Now I cannot SSH into my server anymore.
Is there any way around this?

Thanks

Comment: Contact a server support.

Comment: Most enterprise systems come with a form of [out-of-band-management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-band_management) , ILO, iDrac etc. and many cloud providers provide access to a similar  virtual console which you can use to directly manage a server as if you were using an attached display and keyboard.